# Reboot the PC from USB drive when plugged in

Tags: usb-drive

I installed [Linux Lite](https://www.linuxliteos.com/) on my USB stick. Is it possible that when I plug in my USB, that the currently running OS, for example Windows, would be shut down automatically and the computer would reboot so that it boots from the USB stick?

Comment: Please post general OS questions or on programming barebones SE. Because on narrow and localized SE it's could be offtopic. (OS's hate each other desperately)

Comment: You could possibly set up a script on the drive which is seen by [AutoRun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoRun) to cause Windows to reboot the computer for you, but that would obviously be Windows-specific and is out of the scope of u.SE.  (This comment was previously an Answer and has been moved to the Comment section as it does not, in fact, fully answer the question.)